# Finding page faults using top command

Tags: linux, top

Using top’s sorting capabilities in Linux, how to find the process that has generated the most page faults?

I have tried

```
top
```

then

```
f
```

then choose

```
nMaj
```

I then got a list of processes, but what sorting capabilities should I use next to find the process that has generated the most page faults?

Answer (score 0):

In the same <kbd>f</kbd> dialog press <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> to choose either `vMn` or `vMj` and then press <kbd>s</kbd> depending on which one you want to sort by.